# Error inserting date in mysql

Tags: c#, datetime

I have simple mysql table want to insert inquery details from asp Page please look once the code error;

> "String was not recognized as a valid DateTime"

Please suggest

```
try
{
    MySqlCommand cmd = new MySqlCommand("sp_LeadInfo", mycon);
    cmd.CommandType = CommandType.StoredProcedure;

    string currentDate = System.DateTime.Now.ToString("yyyy-MM-dd hh:mm:ss");

    string dateCheckIn = Convert.ToDateTime(b.checkIn).ToString("yyyy-MM-dd");
    string dateCheckOut = Convert.ToDateTime(b.cheOut).ToString("yyyy-MM-dd");
    cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@txtName", b.name);
    cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@txtEmail", b.email);
    cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@txtPhone", b.phone);
    cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@txtAlternateNo", b.alternateNo);
    cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@txtCheckIn", dateCheckIn);
    cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@txtNight", b.night);
    cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@txtCheckOut",dateCheckOut);
    cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@txtRooms", b.noOfRooms);
    cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@txtAdults", b.adults);
    cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@txtChildren", b.children);
    cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@currDate", currentDate);
    cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@txtMessage", b.message);
    cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@txtStatus","");
    cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@txtRemark", "");

    mycon.Open();
    //cmd.ExecuteNonQuery();
    cmd.ExecuteNonQuery();
    mycon.Close();
}
catch(Exception ex)
{
    throw (ex);
}
```

Comment: what is b.Checkin and b.checkout I think one of then cause the prob

Comment: What is the values of `b.checkIn` and `b.cheOut` and what is your `CurrentCulture`?

Comment: these are string variables declared in bal class

Comment: Check your table and see whether the column currentDate has datatype as date time.Do the same for dateCheckin and dateCheckout

Comment: these variable contain date in string format entered by any user

Comment: hi every one thanks for efforts got the solution actually i was inserting date  in this formate "20-5-2014" in form

Comment: Try not converting the dates / times to strings. Just pass a datetime instance as parameter value. The command implementation should take care of correct fomatting.

Comment: @user3691086 Looks like your `CurrentCulture` doesn't have `dd-M-yyyy` as a a standard date and time format. Take a look at my answer

Answer (score 0):

[`Convert.ToDateTime(string)` method](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/xhz1w05e%28v=vs.110%29.aspx) uses [`DateTime.Parse(string, CultureInfo.CurrentCulture)`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/kc8s65zs%28v=vs.110%29.aspx) explicitly.

Here how it's [impelemented](http://referencesource.microsoft.com/#mscorlib/system/convert.cs#fce604498e2f810b);

```
public static DateTime ToDateTime(String value) {
    if (value == null)
        return new DateTime(0);
    return DateTime.Parse(value, CultureInfo.CurrentCulture);
}
```

These methods uses standard date and time patterns of your [`CurrentCulture`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.globalization.cultureinfo.currentculture%28v=vs.110%29.aspx). Probably the pattern of your string doesn't have a standard format of your current thread culture.

> hi every one thanks for efforts got the solution actually i was
>   inserting date in this formate "20-5-2014" in form

*Well*, sounds like your `CurrentCulture` doesn't have `dd-M-yyyy` format as a standart date and time pattern. You might need to force an input with that format from the user interface side using javascript or ajax vs...

You can find all standard patterns that your current culture supports like;

```
foreach (var pattern in CultureInfo.CurrentCulture.
                                    DateTimeFormat.
                                    GetAllDateTimePatterns())
{
     Console.WriteLine(pattern);
}
```

You can use [`DateTime.TryParseExact`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.datetime.tryparseexact%28v=vs.110%29.aspx) or [`DateTime.ParseExact`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.datetime.parseexact%28v=vs.110%29.aspx) methods to parse your custom date and time formatted strings.

For example;

```
string s = "20-5-2014";
DateTime dt;
if(DateTime.TryParseExact(s, "dd-M-yyyy", CultureInfo.CurrentCulture,
                              DateTimeStyles.None, out dt))
{
    Console.WriteLine(dt);
    Console.WriteLine(dt.ToString("yyyy-MM-dd"));
}
```

Output will be;

```
5/20/2014 12:00:00 AM
2014-05-20
```

Here a <kbd>[**`demonstration`**](http://ideone.com/MzM8JK)</kbd>.